# How to get what's under cursor WebKit.Net

Tags: c#, html, cursor, webkit.net

I'm working on a project in C# and I'm using WebKit Browser. My problem is that i have no idea how to get what's under the cursor.

`E.g: mouse hovers over link -> get the link text` Stuff like that.

I've read something about Java but i don't know Java yet, also i wouldn'T know how to add that to my c# code.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Well by now I've found my answer.

#1, I decided to use open-webkit-sharp which works way better in C#.

#2, I found an event called `StatusTextChanged`, and this StatusText contains the URL of the links when you hover the mouse over them.

Here's a link to open-webkit-sharp: https://code.google.com/p/open-webkit-sharp/

Though so far it seems that they haven'T even replied to anyone in months so I'm not sure if it's still being worked on.